# Flux doOnComplete operator, what are the alternatives that can accept parameters?

Tags: java, asynchronous, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have this simple method which call an external service repeatedly until it gets `completed` as a response,

```
private void status(String id) {
        restClient
                .get(url + "/status/" + id)
                .send(StatusResponse.class)
                .repeatWhen(completed -> completed.delayElements(Duration.ofMillis(2000)))
                .takeUntil(statusResponse->statusResponse.getStatus().equals("completed"))
                .doOnComplete(//HERE I want to work with the object returned from the takeUntil operator)
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Error :: " + e.getMessage(), e))
                .subscribe();
    }
```

I need to do some more calculations after i get the `completed` response, As far as i understand, the best way to do it is on the `doOnComplete` operator, however I the `doOnComplete` operator doesn't have the response from the previous operator. How to read the `statusResponse` object in the `doOnComplete` or what are the alternatives for it ?

Comment: If you only want the response from the completed call, you should replace `doOnComplete` with `.last().map(response -> { ...})`.

Comment: If you read the documentation you will see that `doOnComplete` is for side effects, and not what you want to use it for, you should look into using `map` or `flatMap`

Comment: You might be looking for `.then()` which will allow you to return a `Mono`